# how to cancel the mailto in IE iframe designMode = "on"

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, mailto, designmode

the iframe's property is designMode = "on".
when press some text in iframe with @ in Internet Explorer. 
it automatically converts it to a `mailto:` link.

e.g. `ab@cd` becomes `mailto:ab@cd`

how do I cancel this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in IE 9 and later with `document.execCommand()` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa769893%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

```
document.execCommand("AutoUrlDetect", false, false);
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3ELJD/1/

In earlier versions of IE, you'll have to remove the links yourself.