# How to prevent converting a@b to a mailto link in contenteditable div in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, contenteditable

I am trying to make a widget using contenteditable div where in when we type anything after @ (say @xxx) an ajax call is fired to return the possible suggestions for the matched 'xxx' value. This works fine if I have a space in front of '@' but if there is no space in front of '@' (like so - abc@xxx) the whole thing becomes a mailto link. As far as I think, this is IE's default behavior.

Can anyone help me out in preventing this from happening? Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you show us what you have currently for code?

Comment: It would be really difficult to post the code, but I have created a sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yQ3LA/). Simply enter abc@xyz and press the up or back navigation key on the keyboard. You will see that the text gets converted to a mailto link in Internet Explorer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to cancel the mailto in IE iframe designMode = "on"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835094/how-to-cancel-the-mailto-in-ie-iframe-designmode-on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a command identifier called [`AutoUrlDetect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa769893%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that you can use in `document.execCommand()` to prevent this behaviour (and automatic insertion of all links). Sadly it only works in IE 9 and later.

```
document.execCommand("AutoUrlDetect", false, false);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3ELJD/1/

Comment: Thank you for your response Tim. This works for compat modes in IE9. But I guess I need to test it out in pure IE7 and IE8 browsers.

Comment: @KapilKashyap: I'm pretty sure I've tried it before in real IE 7 and 8 and it hasn't worked. Also, the IE blog mentions it being enabled in IE 9: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/09/15/ie9-beta-minor-change-list.aspx